# Getting past OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion to reinstall Yosemite 10.10

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install

I got Yosemite 10.10, now I want to use reinstall option from recovery menu. I hold <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and see this screen:

[image]

I pick Disk Utility to check if I have disk

[image]

Then I close Disk Utility and open Reinstall OS X and connect to internet via Wi-fi

[image]

After clicking continue and agreeing to the SLA, I see this screen to select the volume to install to:

[image]

But after clicking an unlock button and entering a password it returns me back to the first screen, then again to the agreement screen and then to the volume selector. After that I can't choose any volume because there is no icon anymore like after the first attempt.

[image]

And I can't continue.

After restarting the Mac I see the earth loading indicator and then after I click Reinstall Mac it allows me to reinstall Mountain Lion but there is also no disk even Disk Utility does not show any disk right now.

[image]

Comment: Your Original OSX was Mountain Lion, and the cmd+r has restored it. Now you have to download Yosemite and install it.

Comment: @Buscar웃 how can I download it, is there any options from reinstall menu ?

Comment: My fault, I thought the Mountain Lin is now working!. When you hit the Install the first time, how long did you wait ? It might have started the process (but it is slow to do so). And to clarify, if you do the cmd+r now you get the Lion and not the Yosemite.

Comment: I press cmd r first time and as my latest OS X was Yosemite 10.10 it seems shows me re install option to reinstall it as Yosemite, so but after I select a disk and tap continue button it waits for few seconds and then seems like redirect me to the first steps to agreements and then shows up for me dis selection but there is no disk at this time. I waited to make sure if disk will not appear and then restarted mac but after restarting I have not hold cmd r and it just show me the same menu with reinstall option bout in the second time it was mountain lion not Yosemite as you said it original.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I just add comment here.

Comment: ok, you said you opened the disk utility before doing the install, what did you do there (the pic is to small to see)

Comment: If I see it correctly, the picture shows a grey (unmounted) partition called "Untitled". If this is the case without you unmounting it, boot to recovery again and create a partition using "Mac OS Extended (journaled)" as a format. Then try again to install Mountain Lion (and later Yosemite).

Comment: Picture 2 - is that repairing permissions or repairing Disk? It looks more like permissions. If so, run repair disk.

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander Please boot to Internet Recovery Mode (cmd-alt-R), open Terminal, enter `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list`, take pics of the output and add them to your question. Choose a size which allows me to read the output/OCR it.

Comment: @klanomath how to run terminal? Sorry

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander At the first screen choose in the menubar -> Utilities -> Terminal